# How to query multiple 'Split' in linq?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to execute the following call *("api/test/sin=2129VAH99,8974922&sip=108124AG3")* from the code below, but I cannot seem to get the call to work, as it keeps responding with 'no data' error.

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] Query query)
    {
        var data = db.database_Items.AsQueryable();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query.sip))
        {
            var ids = query.sip.Split(',').ToList();

            data = data.Where(c => ids.Any(i => (c.SIP != null && c.SIP.Contains(i))));
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query.sin))
        {
            var ids = query.sin.Split(',').ToList();

            data = data.Where(c => ids.Any(i => (c.SINs != null && c.SINs.Contains(i))));
        }


        if (!data.Any())
        {

            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
    }
```

Any help/guidance would be very much appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Assuming you are searching for the full `SIP` / `SIN` string, possibly you mean `data = data.Where(c => c.SIP != null && ids.Contains(c.SIP));` ?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I tried using that statement you have suggested above and many more like so and unfortunately, i an still experiencing 'no data error' on the client-end of the api call.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your Url to :

api/test?sin=2129VAH99,8974922&sip=108124AG3